# Angular Chart Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am encountering very strange behaviour of angular chart. I have several charts on my page, and they get updated dynamically. I have the problem that they give the following error after they are updated **the second time**. However they keep on working, even after doing more updates to them after the error, it just shows the error everytime again:

```
Chart.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at Object.o.getMaximumWidth (Chart.min.js:12)
    at t.resize (Chart.min.js:11)
    at n (Chart.min.js:11)
    at Chart.min.js:13
```

I update them the following way:

```
// waiting for data from factory
$scope.$on("New Data", function(event, data, ID) {
        processData(data).then(function(r) {
            buildAgeBar(r.counts, r.ages);
        });
}
var buildAgeBar = function(data, labels) {
        $scope.ageHistogramData = [data];
        $scope.ageHistogramLabels = labels;
        $scope.ageHistogramOptions = {
            responsive: true
        };
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

What could be the cause of this error? Why do they keep on working though?

Comment: Please remove the tag Angular and add AngularJS. Angular is for version 2 and higher.

Comment: @JánHalaša done.